# What is the equivalent for Auth.updateUserAttributes in amplify_auth_cognito

Tags: flutter-dependencies, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-sdk-js, flutter-aws-amplify

[Link 1](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/aws-amplify-adds-support-for-custom-attributes-in-amazon-cognito-user-pools/).

What is the equivalent for

```
const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
const result = await Auth.updateUserAttributes(user, {
    'custom:favorite_flavor': 'Strawberry'
});
```

in Flutter

```
amplify_core: '<1.0.0'
amplify_auth_cognito: '<1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Took a look and found the simple answer that the exact copy over does not exists as i'm sure you have realized at this point.
The link:
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/manageusers/q/platform/js/ will fail to give you any comparable Flutter etc... pages & if you try it will return "Flutter is not supported on this page. Please select one of the following: Javascript."

Unfortunately, Javascript is not supported in android/IOS though there was some stuff out there to partially work with it https://medium.com/flutter-community/using-javascript-code-in-flutter-web-903de54a2000.

**Hopefully this answer will become obsolete over time as more work is put into the needed functionality.**

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30550745)

Comment: The answer is indeed that there is nothing that exists like this currently. However, amplify (the program used) is extremely new. Such features are being added over time, which is why i added the bolded reminder. Currently, all my experience and weeks on the program point to it not existing. IF you still want me to remove @MD.RAKIBHASAN I will, however I am right on this. If you care let me know.